# How do I disable dash + equals on a check box object in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, checkbox

I have a datatemplate xaml that currently looks like this for a report screen

```
   <CheckBox>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 0 5" />
            <RadioButton Content="All Pages" IsChecked="{Binding Path=AllPages}" Margin="0 0 0 5" />
            <RadioButton>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Pages: " Margin="0 3 5 0" />
                    <TextBox Width="130" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </RadioButton>
        </StackPanel>
  </CheckBox>
```

I want to know, how I can disable the default checkbox behavior that uses '-' and '=' as chek and uncheck.

I want to allow the user in that textbox to type in '1-5, 6, 7'  for page ranges, but cannot do so because '-' is checking and unchecking the box

EDIT: I would like to maintain the spacebar functionality of checking + unchecking the checkbox.  For whatever reason, if I am in the textbox and I type space, it doesn't trigger the toggle event, but the '-' and '=' do.

EDIT2: Ideally looking for a xaml fix since I am trying to maintain an MVVM architecture and would prefer not to have code behind

Comment: It should be noted there is absolutely nothing wrong with code-behind in MVVM if the code relates to the View only, and not any business logic. For example, move your `TextBox` outside of your `CheckBox`, and in the `KeyPress` event check if the key is equal to space, and if so check/uncheck the `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 4):

CheckBox.OnKeyDown is the culprit (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox.onkeydown.aspx). I solved this by making a custom CheckBox class that overrides OnKeyDown and does nothing. The VB solution would look like:

```
Public Class IgnoreKeyboardCheckBox
    Inherits CheckBox

    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)
        If e.Key = Key.Space Then
            MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can use this class instead of CheckBox whenever you need the checkbox to ignore keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen here [CheckBox.cs source code in C# .NET](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/SP/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/CheckBox@cs/1/CheckBox@cs), for 2-state checkboxes there is custom behaviour for `Key.Add, Key.Subtract, Key.OemPlus, Key.OemMinus`.

(Programmatically) adding commands didn't work for me. Overriding in a subclass did:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  // Non ThreeState Checkboxes natively handle certain keys.
  if (SuppressNativeKeyDownBehaviour(e.Key))
    return;

  base.OnKeyDown(e);
}

private bool SuppressNativeKeyDownBehaviour(Key key)
{
  switch (key)
  {
    case Key.Add:
    case Key.Subtract:
    case Key.OemPlus:
    case Key.OemMinus:
      return true;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the keyboard shortcuts with empty commands:

```
<RadioButton>
        <KeyBinding Key="OemMinus" Command="{Binding EmptyCommand}"/>
</RadioButton>
```

And in your viewmodel:

// using System.windows.input

```
public Icommand EmptyCommand = ApplicationCommands.NotACommand;
```

Comment: The suggested code does not work for me (WPF on net 6).