# c# wpf disable checkbox unchecking when - or + is typed

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Okay my problem is simple:
I have a checkbox with a textbox like that:

```
<CheckBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="FilterTextBox">Custom-Filter</TextBox>
</CheckBox>
```

Now I just want to type in a string with a "-" symbol in it. But unluckily there is something like a KeyPress event in the standard checkbox class from wpf. I didn't even know that function, but if you press "-" it will uncheck the checkbox and if u press "+" it will check it. So I can't type a string with a "-" in it. But I need to do that!

How can i disable that keypress event or override it to do nothing?

I found one similar question here: [How do I disable dash + equals on a check box object in xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158195/how-do-i-disable-dash-equals-on-a-check-box-object-in-xaml)

But it doesnt helped me, cause none of these answers seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am sorry that answer **actualy did** work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37743639/6903474

But is there no other solution for that problem? Mabye something more easy where i do not have to make a new class and override that methode?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. this is kind of a hack, but i think it should work.

First of all,define the `CheckBox` as `ThreeState`, and add a event handler for the indeterminate event:

```
<CheckBox IsThreeState="True"  Indeterminate="CheckBox_Indeterminate">
    <TextBox x:Name="FilterTextBox">Custom-Filter</TextBox>
</CheckBox>
```

And the event handler would be something like this:

```
private void CheckBox_Indeterminate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((CheckBox)sender).IsChecked = false;
}
```